# How do I add columns to database without users losing data when a new version of the application is published?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I have a c# .NET application with a SQLLocalDB database. I have used database first to create the EF6 model.  I have added columns to one of the tables using SQL Server Management Studio and then used 'Update model from database' to propagate the changes into my model.  When doing this, data on the development PC is unaffected and incorporates the new columns.  However, when a different user runs the new version of the application, their existing datafile (.mdf) won't recognise the new columns and crashes with the exception:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'VAT_long_description'
```

making the user's existing data in that table unreachable.  I appreciate that Code First gives the ability to migrate data, but this facility appears not to be available when building the EF model using database first.

My connectionString is:

`<add name="PMMEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/PMMData.csdl|res://*/PMMData.ssdl|res://*/PMMData.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(localdb)\v11.0; AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\PMM.mdf; initial catalog=PMM;Integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True; App=EntityFramework&quot;"providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`

I want to ensure that when a user installs a new version, their .mdf datafile will adapt to the new database schema without loss of data.  It seems the only way to do this is through running a conversion or migration method on startup if the app throws the “Invalid column name” SQL exception.  Where can I find the code (or a NuGet package) that will do this?

Comment: Write a SQL query to add columns to existing mdf file and have user update the database using your update query.  Users can run query in SQL Server Database Manager or you can write an application to add the columns.

Comment: This could well be the answer if the code to update the SQL columns can be included in the main application (my users do not have access to SSMS/SSDM) and fired if the SQL exception described in my original post is triggered.  In that case, I assume the user would need to be prompted to re-start the application for the DB change to take effect.  Is that correct?

Comment: The mdf file needs to be updated before the Update Model.  Normally a version number is put into the database so operator does not have to ask if the database needs to be updated.  If the Update to mdf and update to model are done at same time no restarting is necessary.

Comment: Many thanks.  I will struggle to write the code for this from scratch - can you point me to any code examples or guidance notes on updating the mdf file and the model from within an application?

Comment: The updating of columns is simple and can be done with nay SQL.  See if this helps : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/

Comment: Thanks again, but this is the core of my problem - I created my model using database first, not code first, and it doesn't support migrations.  I will look again at this, but trying to run the Enable-Migrations command in Package Manager Console gives me the error: "Could not load file or assembly 'file:///...\Documents\Visual Studio 
2013\Projects\PersonalMoneyManagement\packages\EntityFramework.6.3.0\tools\EntityFramework.PowerShell.Utility.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: Did you download these utilities : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/download-tools-nuget

Comment: I have downloaded and installed them, and run PM>Enable-Migrations, but my Solution now will not build and throws multiple errors relating to double definitions and table ambiguities.  Not sure where to go from here but suspect I will need to delete the model and rebuild it.

Comment: Did you do a clean build (or delete the bin folder).  You need to force all the obj intermediate files to get recompiled.  I believe some of the modules are not getting rebuilt so there are reference to old database.  I would also open model to make sure the updated model is correct.

Comment: @jdweng, thank you for your continuing feedback.  I see that I can add the columns to the user's mdf file through code in my application.  Your earlier post referred to the need to update the mdf file before the model, but this is not possible with existing users - if I publish a new version of the application (and model) to users whose mdf files reflect the old model, that will always throw an exception.  I would therefore need to catch that, update the user's mdf file with code and then ask the user to re-load the application.  Is this logical?

Comment: That is why I said include a version number in the database.  Once you can check the version then you should not get an exception.  There is also an issue I seen after updating the mdf by adding a table the c# doesn't recognize the changes until the SSMS service is restarted.  So you may need to catch the exception under certain conditions.

Comment: I now see a way forward, thank you - I still need to do the coding for DB changes but will embark on that route.  I can add a version number to the user's configuration table, which fortunately also includes a "Last_updated" column for the last time the application was run, and test both to see if an update is required.  Thanks again for all your help. Not sure how I can mark this comment thread as an answer, but I hope it might be helpful to others coming to it.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using MVC , you have two methods to make an update in your models class database. the most easy way to resolve that issue is that you delete the model class related to the database and you import it again into your model folder. don't worry about data, they will still stored in your database. unless you have wrotten some extra object in the model class database, in this case you will waste those extra objects.. it will not affect your storage.

Comment: This is not an ASP.Net web application and I am therefore not using MVC.  I am also not convinced I could do the deletion of the model class and the importing of a new model (with the new columns added) entirely in code within the existing application, so that it is invisible to the user.  I will, however, explore this.  Thank you.